# No response from Socket.IO in Node.JS server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

Guys i've been struggled for this past days, from this socket.io setup. I thought there's should be no mistakes on my code. I've followed all tutorial and documentation on how to setup the server for socket.io using node and express. But still when i try to connect to this there are no response from the socket.io. On my client side i try to connect the same url as this server running http://localhost:8090 (FIXED)

**SO EVERYTHING IS SET UP! the thing that it won't work is bcs i didn't set the CORS(see my edited code) on the socket instance on the server side.FYI since Socket.IO v3 u need to include the cors property by defining which url that gonna connected to ur socket.**

**Server Code:**

```
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser =  require('cookie-parser');
const db = require("./Connection/pg_pool");
const authentication = require("./Config/auth");
const connectionError = require("./Config/connectionError");
const cors = require('cors');
let port = 8090;
let hostname = 'localhost';
const midtransClient = require('midtrans-client');
const paymentConf = require('./Config/payment');
const { encode } = require('node-encoder');
const axios = require('axios');

let payment =  paymentConf.paymentConf;
let errorMsg = connectionError.connectionError();
let auth = authentication.auth;

const app = express();

const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log('NEW USER CONNECTED')
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());

server.listen(process.env.PORT || port, hostname, () => {    
    console.log(`Listening to ${hostname}:${port}`)
})
```

***Client Code:***

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback, useMemo} from 'react';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8090";
let socket;

export default function Chat(props) {

  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const [req, setReq] = useState([]);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [send, setSend] = useState(false);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    console.log('ini socker', socket.connected)
    socket.on("connect", (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    });    
  }, []);
....
```

**FIXED CODE**

```
/*since my frontend (client-side) was running on localhost:3000,
all u need to do is just define the cors and put the origin url that 
u gonna connect to ur socket instance on Node.Js (server) like this.*/

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: [`http://localhost:3000`],
      credentials: true
    }
})
```

Comment: Please share your client code too.

Comment: hi @TusharShahi i edited this question already

Comment: @GilbertKho do u see any errors on console, can u check the network tab ? , also there is cors options u must specify when your client is not served from the same origin as your server.

Comment: @Arslan noo, there are no errors on console on the client or the server side. that's why i'm so confused abt what actually wrong on my code. i've followed all the steps correctly. and as u can see already use cors options on my node.js

Comment: @GilbertKho u have to use cors options with socket io client as well

Comment: FYI, i made a new project and it worked! but when i tried to run my own server it won't show any indication that my socket.io is running or not.